# Weird symbol after editing filename through dirent

Tags: c, malloc, strcat

I'm using dirent.h to loop inside dir recursivly.
I want to edit the name of a file then past his data and his new name to a new file.

Here i can loop and edit his name with a new extension (.enc), the only problem is that weird symbol appear between my PATH and my D_NAME (aka "fn" after edit).

Here is my code and an exemple.

```
while(1)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    const char *d_name;
    unsigned char d_type;

    entry = readdir(d);
    if(!entry)
    {
        // no more entries in this directory -> break the loop
        break;
    }

    d_name = entry->d_name;
    d_type = entry->d_type;

    if(strcmp(d_name, ".")!=0)
    {
        if(strcmp(d_name, "..")!=0)
        {
            if(d_type == DT_REG)
            {
                if(de_flag=='e')
                {
                    char *fn = NULL;
                    fn = malloc(400*sizeof(char));
                    strcat(fn, d_name);
                    strcat(fn, ".enc");

                    char abs1_path[PATH_MAX];
                    snprintf(abs1_path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", name, fn);

                    char ch;
                    char abs_path[PATH_MAX];
                    snprintf(abs_path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", name, d_name);

                    printf("%s             %s\n", abs1_path, abs_path);
                    FILE *source, *target;
                    //source = fopen(abs_path, "r");
                    //target = fopen(abs1_path, "w");
```

As u can see, on the first lap of the loop, there is no problem on the new filename
So i think the problem comes from the malloc() or something like this. (i use free(fn)) after, but dont wanted to show ALL the source code.
[image]

Comment: `fn = malloc(400*sizeof(char));  strcat(fn, d_name);` - `fn` contains garbage, you can't `strcat` with it.

Comment: With `fn = malloc(400*sizeof(char)); strcat(fn, d_name);` you made the false assumption that `malloc` initialises the memory: it does not. the first `strcat` should be `strcpy`

Comment: Guys you're insane, strcat into strcpy was a huge call, 3 days of searching for this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: A `fn = calloc(400, sizeof char);` would have worked. A `fn[0] = '\0';` right after the `malloc` too.

Comment: You should get used to run your program in a debugger. Stepping through that function and inspect your variables should show this in 10 minutes.

Comment: I recommend using `pathconf` for finding the permitted name length rather than the hardcoded 400, and using `strncat` or `snprintf`.